# Vector of different n values in rbeta

Tags: r

I would like to simultaneously use vectors of different parameter values in rbeta and get out a vector whose length is the sum of the elements of the n vector.  For example,

```
n <- c(10, 20, 30)
alpha <- c(1,2,3)
beta <- c(3,2,1)
rbeta(n, alpha, beta)
```

The bottom line doesn't do what I would like.  I want the output to be a vector of length 10+20+30 = 60, with the first 10 elements being 10 samples from a beta(1,3), the next 20 elements from a beta(2,2) and the next 30 elements from a beta(3,1).  What is the best way to do this?

Comment: `rbeta(sum(n), 2, 1)`.....?

Answer (score 3):

In general when applying a function to the elements of a vector, you’d need to `lapply` over your input vector:

```
unlist(lapply(n, rbeta, 2, 1)
```

However, in your case you can simply `sum` all the `n`s:

```
rbeta(sum(n), 2, 1)
```

If you have multiple parameters for `alpha` and `beta`, you can use [`Map`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/funprog.html) instead (careful, arguments are inverted compared to `lapply`):

```
unlist(Map(rbeta, n, alpha, beta))
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I realized my question was not detailed enough so I edited it.  In my case I actually will want different values of alpha and beta so I can't just sum the n vector.

Comment: @SarahK In that case, `lapply` or its sister `mapply` is your friend.

Comment: you also need to be careful about `mapply`'s `SIMPLIFY` parameter, if you happen to have a vector of equal `n` values ...

Comment: @BenBolker Dang, how could I forget this?! I always use `Map` for that reason.

Answer (score 1):

For your revised question I think judicious use of `rep()` will make it work.

```
n <- c(10, 20, 30)
alpha <- c(1,2,3)
beta <- c(3,2,1)
rbeta(sum(n),rep(alpha,n),rep(beta,n))
```